# Can I charge a my Li-Ion batteries using a regular power adaptor?

Tags: power, batteries, battery-charging

I'm confused with the various websites and advice on this. I want to use 3×18650 cells (3.7V, 2200mAh each) connected in series to supply my device with +-11V. To charge them, can I just connect my pack to a 12V DC power adapter (2A), or do I need some additional components?

Comment: (not quite) instant death! THere is a large amount on this site on charging LiIon batteries, how to do it well , how to do it badly, and why doing it badly is a bad idea. | 3S LiIon needs 12.6V for a full charge. 12.0V is actually potentially good for them.  BUT  there is more to it than that. Search this site and look at www.batteryuniversity.com and then ask re what you still need to know.

Comment: Look through   [**these**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3288+charging+liion) and  [**these**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=charging+liion)

Comment: Indeed, **NO**. When your batteries are quite empty too much current might flow and that will damage your batteries. A proper charging circuit is needed. See the list of related questions on the right -->  and start reading. In my opinion **no one** should even be allowed to touch unprotected lithium based cells before understanding the basics of how to use them.

Comment: Perhaps this is actually a very useful question that needs a good and "authoritative" answer. That answer being a very long version of *NO*. I'm sure a lot of people are asking this.

Comment: Ditto to the above comments. Do not even think of trying it. Li-Ion batteries need to be treated with kid gloves when it comes to their usage and are hugely more dangerous and prone to catastrophic failure than older types of battery technology.

Comment: Well, you can probably do it, and there's a fair chance it won't explode the first time if your cells are balanced and the power supply doesn't burn. Of course, as they will unbalance with use, subsequent charges will eventually result in catastrophic failure, it's only a matter of time. And you don't want that to happen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hm18s-NYLZU#t=0m30s

Comment: Learn all about batteries:  http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/  Learn why you likely do not have 3.7 volt, 2200mAh Lithium Manganese Oxide batteries.  A why it is more likely to be a 3.6V Lithium Cobalt Oxide.

Comment: Thanks all. I was hoping to skip some of the complexity for my hobby project, but I guess I need to learn about charging circuits as well

Comment: Depending on 12V source a poor man's way of charging fresh batteries could use 12V with a current limiter to charge 4V per cell, but if they are not perfectly matched then the weakest cell may exceed 4v while the others are still charging up so a balancer is needed.  then auto cutoff when the charge current drops to 10% of initial current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not.

First off batteries need to be charged with current limiting. If you just give it unregulated access to current the batteries will get hot and potentially catch fire.

In addition to that a series arrangement of batteries must be balanced charged so that no one cell is much higher than the other. A danger is that even if the average voltage is within the acceptable range one of the cells might be higher and get overcharged which can make it, you guessed it, catch fire.

Such arrangements of batteries need a proper balance charging device that has access to not just the + and - at the end, but also taps between each battery in the form of balance leads.